# Как прорваться через 401 Unauthorized ошибку?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Пытаюсь скачать кусок трансляции по адресу [Live](http://mlsh.co:2086/live/jake/jake1/26685.ts)

Получаю ошибку 401. Когда качаю с помощью ffmpeg то все ок, но ffmpeg очень медленный и требует чтоб файл сразу перекодировался.
Хочу качать куски вот так:

```
var url = @"http://mlsh.co:2086/live/jake/jake1/26685.m3u8";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"c:\output.ts");
```

Как обойти эту ошибку?

Comment: пробовал другим useragent'ом притвориться?

Comment: @adrug Нет. Попробую, но сперва есть ли способ узнать useragent vlc или ffmpeg когда они общаются с сервером и тянут стрим?

Comment: из всех способов, которые существуют я знаю лишь 
 что можно перехватить запрос  снифером типа fiddler

Comment: Там и узнаешь что они(vlc/ffmped) еще дополнительно шлют такого на что сайт им отвечает.

Comment: @adrug Спасибо за инфу! Буду пробовать

Comment: «ffmpeg очень медленный и требует чтоб файл сразу перекодировался» — ничего подобного, он умеет сохранять без перекодирования через `-c copy`

Comment: @andreymal да, оказалось умеет, когда разобрался с параметрами, но все равно медленно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас открывается что то и где то, то надо это приложение изучить, к примеру отловив все его запросы через какую либо программу, к примеру, `Fiddler`.

Допустим, открываем указанную ссылку в плеере (в моем случае это `IP-TV Player`), смотрим отправленный запрос (вы их не пропустите, обычно если это поток, то запросов летит куча):

[image: img1]

Смотрим заголовки запроса:

```
GET http://178.132.6.125/live/jak....... HTTP/1.1
Host: 178.132.6.125
User-Agent: VLC/2.2.8 LibVLC/2.2.8
Range: bytes=0-
Connection: close
Icy-MetaData: 1
```

Обычно этого достаточно для того, что бы получить необходимый доступ, в некоторых случаях доступ может быть скрыт в `Cookies`, которые мы отправляем серверу.

Давайте попробуем отправить элементарный запрос с подменой `User-Agent` заголовка:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "VLC/2.2.8 LibVLC/2.2.8");
client.DownloadFile("http://mlsh.co:2086/live/jake/jake1/26685.m3u8", "test.m3u8");
```

В `Fiddler` видим два запроса, отправленный нами со статусом `302` (редирект) и 2-ой запрос со статусом `200` (успешно). Проверяем наш скачанный файл и видим, что он успешно получен.

[image: img2]

Вот собственно и все, простейшая подмена заголовков открыла нам доступ к необходимому адресу. Удачи!

Comment: Большущее спасибо! Вчера до утра мучал Fiddler, но почему-то так и не увидел запросов от VLC  и вообще Fiddler постоянно подвисал и не отображал http запросы, так и не разобрался в чем дело. Еще раз спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: @Ghsee сам `Fiddler` работает по принципу `Proxy` сервера и стандартно для отладки он использует адрес `127.0.0.1:8888`. В некоторых программах надо руками настроить отправку запросов на этот адрес. Можете попробовать в VLC указать в настройках (Инструменты->Настройки->Ввод/кодеки->HTTP-прокси). По поводу зависания, тут уже не помогу, ибо должно изначально пару окон выдать для настройки и все, отлавливать все запросы.

Comment: когда настраиваю прокси в VLC стримы перестают работать. Вот такой вывод Fiddler'a получаю когда все по дефолту https://yadi.sk/i/BIhxjhzi3TxjDt т.е он вообще не видит VLC. Когда запускаю браузер, получаю некоторый вывод. Как так может быть? Когда в фидлере указываю какой именно процесс просматривать(vlc), vlc вообще перестает тянуть стримы

Comment: @Ghsee Попробуйте указать прокси как Url адрес (с `http://` в начале)

Comment: Все получилось. Adguard блочил