# Правильный парсинг с помощью C#

Tags: c#, парсер, текст

Всем привет. Задался целью написать парсер, который бы получал текст с этой страницы: https://litnet.com/reader/zhestkii-start-tom-i-b59468
Но вся проблема в том, что здесь он в исходный код, при переключении страниц (не глав), не помещается, там остается то, что было на самой первой странице. Я так понимаю, он подгружается по мере продвижения пользователя по книге. По этой причине обычный парсинг (без куков и тому подобного) с помощью HTML Agillity Pack не подходит.
Я предполагаю, что надо отправлять запрос на получение ответа от сервера, получать оттуда нужные данные и вставлять в свой следующий запрос.
Но проблема: как это правильно организовать я не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, статьи, где об этом можно почитать. Желательно на русском)
Ну или, если не будет кому-то лень, сразу готовый пример, который поможет мне в этом разобраться и переписать под себя.

Comment: Всё просто , отключите JavaScript в вашем браузере, и посмотрите на страницу новым взглядом, там и придёт понимание, что текст грузится JavaScript ом, по событию onClick

Comment: Ваш сайт работает путем отправки обычного `POST` запроса на адрес `/reader/get-page`. Смотрите что именно отправляет через [Fiddler](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/807475/220553) или что то подобное и эмулируйте, путем [отправки запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777512/220553)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сейчас использование Fiddler для анализа запросов, сравнимо с ездой на лошадях, браузеры имеют все необходимые инструменты для анализа запросов без проксирования.

Comment: пост запрос совсем не простой , сначала вызывается вот эта страница `https://litnet.com/reader/ad?chapter_id=482053`  с вашим ID  и множественными параметрами кукки, всё это обрабатывается JavaScript скрипт не обфусцирован к счастью можно написать интерпретатор на C#.  но есть ещё подводные камни , без обработки js первой страницы ссылку не получить, по этому нужно двигаться в направлении полной обработки js.

Comment: Думаю здесь лежит ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745960/c-cefsharp-offscreen-как-его-использовать-как-получить-html-с-уже-выполненным

Comment: @DigitalCore Ну кое-как исходный текст страницы получить удалось. Только есть проблемка: он зашифрован. Пример: https://pastebin.com/BW0BMEWW Не подскажете в сторону чего смотреть, чтобы расшифровать содержимое? Простой очистки html-тегов недостаточно, там буквы идут вразброс.

Comment: Нечего там не зашифровано... Просто добавлен "мусор" в виде html тегов. Уберите их и оставьте то, что за ними. То есть там `<span ...>мусор</span> текст`. Вот все внутренности тега `span` и его самого вам надо убрать.

Comment: @АндрейФедоров используйте `await doc.GetTextAsync()` вместо `await doc.GetSourceAsync()` - получите текст без разметки и мусора.